# Shift struck when try to put it in to 1st gear

Tags: manual-transmission, shifting, gears, gear-stick

I have a Nissan N16 car with a 5 speed manual gearbox.
I have a issue with its shift. When I try to shift into 1st gear,
it is very hard to put it in - but not in to other gears.
I have to push harder to shift to 1st. not smooth.

However, sometimes it works smoothly. I have tried pressing the clutch and different levels but nothing makes any difference.
Why does this happen?

Comment: Agreed with the above. Either maladjusted clutch or the synchro. Check out the top two answers in the linked post.

Comment: @mibseLucifer not the grinding. I know grinding but this is different. It is something like stick is not move to 1st gear position as there is something obstructing its path

Comment: @Milan  Is it hard to go in when you are stopped also?  Is it easier when you shut off the vehicle?